# how to close all background threads of a Windows Service application ?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I have created a windows service application , In that i open about 10000 threads , I want to close all threads just like all background threads get closed when I close winform applications , how can I accomplish this ? i don't want to store reference to all these threads in an array and close all by using a loop.

Before I used a Winform application and when I closed the winform application all backgrounds threads get closed itself. I want to accomplish something like that to close all threads in Windows Service application

Any idea will be very appreciated.

Comment: If you just handle the stop message and do nothing else, the OS should stop all the threads after ~20 secs.

Comment: I am not clear what you mean ? Did you mean if I just overdie the OnStop message and do nothing it stop all threads ? or did you mean if I don't overide the OnStop method it will close all threads ?

Comment: In my override it just has 'base.OnStop();'

Comment: I tried it but It didn't close all threads, are you sure calling base.OnStop really close all threads ?

Comment: Hi martin james, please post your answer as an answer , I will mark it as the answer, becuase that helped me.

Comment: Ok, done.  The OnStop call just acks the stop message to the OS, but does not, in itself, stop the other threads.  About 20 secs later, the OS 'notices' that the service process still exists, (because of the other threads), and force-terminates the process, stopping all the threads etc.

Comment: Why are you opening 10,000 threads?  That's far, far too many to be appropriate for virtually any situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the thread property `myThread.isBackground = true`, the thread will die as all the foreground threads are killed (when you close the application).

However, creating 10 000 threads is not a good thing as the operating system will spend more time switching between the threads than actually executing the threads' code. Executing that much thread on normal computers will actually be less efficient than executing 2 - 16 threads (for example) on a 2 - 4 cores CPU.

Here's an excellent e-book on threading.

PDF : http://www.albahari.info/threading/threading.pdf
Web : http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: If all foreground threads are killed, backgrounds threads will end too ? So if the application is closed, all backgrounds threads will end as well like the OP wants without keeping tracks of all of them.

Comment: So If using that many threads are not a good practice , can you please tell me what way I should use to create a TCP server that serve 10000 Clients

Comment: Assuming that the whole process is executed on a single machine, you can use a thread pool that allows you to queue work items. Everything is very well explained in the ebook a linked in my answer (http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Thread_Pooling).

Answer (score -1):

I can see two options to achieve your goal :

1. Have your Service Application to start another Executable program that is responsible for starting your threads. Then have your service application to kill that Executable program when needed. The threads spawned by the Executable program will be killed but not the service.
2. Put a break condition in your running thread. Through setting a boolean flag you could have your threads exiting the `while (true)` and exit the Runnable delegate. (Here I assume your threads are constantly running in a `while (true)`, otherwise you would not ask that question).

Comment: It's nothing to doubt, it's a server so it has to be running.

Comment: I meant that they are not all the the running state, ie. most/all blocked on something, (network read, presumably).

Comment: @MartinJames Ok ok, I should have wrote "alive" instead of "running". They can't be "blocked" for eternity, except if there is a problem with the implementation. One second or another they will run some code and eventually test the break condition.

Answer (score -2):

If you just handle the stop message and do nothing else, the OS should stop all the remaining threads in the service process after ~20 secs.

Comment: Why downvote?  I have tested this, it works.  It works if the threads are blocked.  It works if the thread are sleeping. It works if the threads are running.

Comment: The OP's question basically boils down to "I have no idea what I'm doing. How can I get out of the hole I am in?" The correct answer from VinceAnity is, "Learn how to do what you are doing before doing it. And here's a good start." Unfortunately, your answer amounts to, "You don't need to know what you're doing. The OS will auto-magically clean up for you." Even though this is becoming a common outlook on software development these days it's still a terrible one.

Comment: @StephenMartin  why terrible?  Given a complex, multithreaded app in a gnerally-unpredictable state at the time you wish to shut it down, how do you propose to stop it?  a) Design, develop, write, test a load of complex, difficult, probably unreliable thread-shutdown code that struggles to stop threads in both blocked and running states.  b) Call ExitProcess(0).  'Cleanly shutting down threads' with user code is, in many apps, just unrealistic.  Only the OS has the tools to stop all threads in all states on all cores, before releasing resources in use.